# Is it possible to determine which font-files pdflatex uses for a compilation

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am trying to make a small portable texlive package. For this I need to clear out the fonts (they take 1.7GB).

So having a few example documents, can I somehow determine which font files in the latex font directory are used by pdflatex during compilation?

Comment: pdftex shows all fonts used in the log file by default

Comment: Also you can take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

Comment: During the installation of texlive, you can select which font collections should be installed. For example if you only deal with western texts, deselect all asian related things. Did you already do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just by way of example, this is what I get from a recent example file. I ran again `pdflatex` with the `-recorder` command line option, which created a file with extension `.fls`:

```
PWD <removed>
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf.cnf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
INPUT luca.tex
OUTPUT luca.log
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/texfonts.map
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec/ecrm1000.tfm
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-italian/italian.ldf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-italian/italian.ldf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textgreek/textgreek.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textgreek/textgreek.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/lgrenc.def
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/lgrenc.def
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/greek-fontenc.def
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/greek-fontenc.def
INPUT luca.aux
INPUT luca.aux
OUTPUT luca.aux
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmr.fd
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmr.fd
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cbfonts/grmn1000.tfm
OUTPUT luca.pdf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
INPUT luca.aux
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cbfonts/grmn1000.pfb
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb
```

You can easily see the `.tfm` and `.pfb` files you need. However, recall that the `.tfm` font files loaded at format creation are not shown (they are the Computer Modern fonts, in a standard installation).

Also `.vf` files are listed, if needed.